# Appending formdata with additional key value pair and retrieving in WebAPI controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload a file using webapi and adding additional parameters to formdata. But i couldnt able to get those additional param values in Controller.

My Ajax call will looks like

```
 var userdata = new FormData();
                    userdata.append('file', files[0]);
                    userdata.append('CustomerId',"Raju");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/api/Blob",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: userdata,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        success: function (messages) {
                            alert("File uploaded Succeesfully");
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("Error while invoking the Web API");
                        }
                    });
```

and in controller am trying to retrieve the customer id and value as "Raju" by using the following line

```
 var parameters = fileData.Headers.ContentDisposition.Parameters;
```

In parameters i have two params, First was the file i attached and second was a key value pair which has 
Name : Name 
Value : CustomerId

but i want get 
Name : "CustomerId"
Value: Raju

Please help on this.